# Google Vignette Ads <ins> always have "display: none" in Next JS

Tags: next.js, ads, google-ads-api, adsense, vignette

I tried a lot of ways to enable the Vignette ads on the Next JS site before I realized that there always was a  block for them in the inspector, it just never change "display: none" to "display: block".

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle adsbygoogle-noablate" style="display: none !important; width: 100vw !important; height: 100vh !important; inset: 0px auto auto 0px !important; clear: none !important; float: none !important; margin: 0px !important; max-height: none !important; max-width: none !important; opacity: 1 !important; overflow: visible !important; padding: 0px !important; position: fixed !important; vertical-align: baseline !important; visibility: visible !important; z-index: 2147483647 !important; background: transparent !important;" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" aria-hidden="true" data-vignette-loaded="true" data-ad-status="filled"></ins>
```

How i saw on other sites this ins appear and after some interaction with the site display automatically changed from none to block and Vignette Ads appear.
If I manually change in the inspector display to block - Vignette will appear immediately, but automatically never.

Please can anyone know a possible solution?

Comment: Vignette ad becomes visible when user clicks any link on the page. Are you saying that in your case the ad is never shown, even after you click on a link?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mikita, yes, that's right, to navigate through the pages of the Next JS site I use `Router.push(path)` from next/router and ad is never shown. Maybe Google doesn't recognize these clicks?

Comment: Yes, currently vignette ads support only standard navigation through clicks where no JS is intercepting/preventing default behavior. No framework-based, single-page apps navigations supported yet.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Mikita, for your answer! May you please clarify just in case, there is no way to change the navigation in single-page app to show the vignette ads?

Comment: That's correct. You can't use vignette ads with single page app at the moment.

Comment: I am very thankful for your consideration! You saved me from the endless search for answer! Thanks a lot!